# Вывод информации в DataGridView в зависимости от выбора в другом DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server

У меня есть 2 DataGridView. Необходимо, чтобы при выборе значения в первом  DataGridView во втором DataGridView выводились только значения, связанные с этой строчкой.
То есть при выборе в первом DataGridView Определенного рациона, во втором должен отображаться список продуктов, которые входят в этот рацион со всей соответствующей информацией.
Сложность заключается в том, что между 2 таблицами, которые нужно связать таким образом есть промежуточная таблица. Как это можно реализовать?
[image]

Comment: [master/detail](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая DataGridView - таблица с рационами. Для заполнения второй таблицы берем id записи из первой таблицы, в моем примере id хранится в первом столбце (это можно сделать множеством способов). Будем обрабатывать событие SelectionChanged первой DataGridView. У первой DataGridView SelectionMode = FullRowSelect

```
 private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT Продукты.[Код продукт], Продукты.Продукт, Продукты.Поставщик, Продукты.Стоимость FROM Продукты INNER JOIN [Учет продуктов] ON Продукты.[Код продукт] = [Учет продуктов].КодПродукта INNER JOIN Рационы ON [Учет продуктов].КодРациона = Рационы.[Код рациона]    Where Рационы.[Код рациона] = " + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), sqlConnection);
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = sc.ExecuteReader())
                if (sdr != null)
                    if (sdr.HasRows)
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                            for (int i = 0; i < sdr.FieldCount; i++)
                                dataGridView2[i, dataGridView2.RowCount - 1].Value = sdr[i];
                        }
            sc.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```